How to Override Logging for a Specific Named Refit Client in .NET 6 While Maintaining Unique HTTP Client Names
This is my logging setting in app settings and I am working in .NET 6
 "Logging": {
   "LogLevel": {
     "Default": "Information",
     "System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SdkNameOfMyProject": "None"
   }
 }

I am setting httpClientName as the SdkNameOfMyProject because I want to override specific System.Net.Http.HttpClient but now the problem is httpClientName should be unique for Named HTTP Clients
How can I overcome this issue I should set a unique name as well for my HTTP clients in Refit Client and at the same time my logging should also work for `System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SdkNameOfMyProject
